# Error: Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=list]

Tags: r, window

```
diffPoly <- rmapshaper::ms_erase(combined.poly, sp1.poly)  
Error in rcpp_geojson_to_sf(geojson, expand_geometries) : 
  Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=list].
```

I'm very new to r, and never seen this type of error

if I click debugging,

```
function (geojson, expand_geometries) 
{
  .Call(`_geojsonsf_rcpp_geojson_to_sf`, geojson, expand_geometries)
}
```

this is what I get
I tried upgrading the packages but didn't worked
Can anyone help me with this error?